# how to find the nearest new point that has the same line length?

Tags: math

So I have a path with a start and end points.   I want to move the end point with a users touch event so that the user can drag the line end to different spots but I want to keep the line the same length?   what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: To be the same length from a fixed point, you prescribe a circle.

Comment: See here for an example: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/circle-drag-test/6577174171172864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the start point remains stationary, then all possible end points will be on a circle.

The common way to implement this is to calculate the angle made by the user's touch, the center of the circle (or the starting point in this case), and the "x-axis".

After calculating the angle, use trigonometry to find out the position of the end point:

```
x = rcos(theta)
y = rsin(theta)

where theta is the angle made by the user's touch, the end point, and the start point
and where r is the fixed distance between the starting and ending points.
```

Here's an example of it in action:

[tada](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/circle-drag-test/6577174171172864)